# How to connect an existing Google Cloud project to a Google Playstore console user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-console

I have an existing Google Cloud project, and a Google Play Developer API account.

In the Google Play console 'API access' area, if I try to Link to an existing Google Cloud project then my existing Google Cloud project does not appear in the drop down list.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Found it - from within the Google Cloud project you have to enable the 'Google Play API'

Comment: to be specific, you need to enable the 'Google Play Android Developer API' in your google cloud project